VideoView with kotlin and android studio
I have  a videoView in my layout and a code to play it, and work but on the left side of the video have a black line and this happend with all the video who i place
i think is a propriety default from andyour textroid studio but i dont what i do to remove this
my function to play video```private fun playVideo() {
        val videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + requireActivity().packageName + "/" + R.raw.videooooo)
        Log.d("VideoPlayer", "URI do vídeo: $videoUri")

        try {
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri)
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
                mediaPlayer.isLooping = false
            }
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener {
                Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Vídeo reproduzido completamente.")
            }

            val mediaController = MediaController(requireContext())
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)

            videoView.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
                mediaController.show()
                false
            }
            videoView.start()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("VideoPlayer", "Erro ao reproduzir vídeo: ${e.message}", e)
        }
    }


I think the issue here is videoview not properly handling the size of the video and aligning to the right of the videoview.Try changing the width to match_parent and height to wrap_content in videoView , and for the video in center you can try android:layout_centerInParent="true" in xml inside VideoView tag. You can also try to scale the video in code using the scaling mode inside the setOnPreparedListener
videoView.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
        mediaPlayer.isLooping = false
        mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT)
    }

but be careful scaling the video may introduce other issues like stretching. try getting the width and height of the device screen and aspect ratio of the video you are playing and try to scale accordingly.
